# Relay connection with parameters not getting reloaded on Field_Change mutation

Tags: cookies, reactjs, store, relay, mutation

My app loads a list/connection on startup and I'm using FB login. For auth with Relay I'm setting a cookie but the cookie is removed in case the app is removed from running in the background.
To avoid that the user has to login again I'm caching (AsyncStorage) the user info, if the user exists in there I'm auto login the user at the server so I get my Cookie back. The problem is that I need to reset/reload the connection, I tried a mutation with Field_Change returning the parent (which should include all it's children but it doesn't load the connection which is a child of a child).
I also tried to reset/recreate the store, also without success.
The list is loaded on my start page so I'm not changing pages.

My connection does have multiple params for paging as well as others and an @include.

The only way I could get it to work is to use forceUpdate in the component that also defines the connection, is there a better way?

Update:
Here's the fat query:

```
fragment on AuthorizationChangePayload @relay(pattern: true) {
    viewer {
      user
    }
  }
```

And the config for the mutation:

```
return [{
  type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
  fieldIDs: {
    viewer: this.props.viewer.id
  }
}];
```

Within user there's the connection which doesn't get updated, I didn't specify it as it has parameters and really I want to update the whole user and it's children objects.

Comment: How does your mutation's fat query look like?

Comment: My fat query is only the parent as all the children change, I have something to this extend: ```viewer { user { stuff, connection} } ``` as a schema. My fat query is viewer (I tried viewer { user } as well) and I see with the mutation it also sends the query for stuff (within the user) but not the connection which on this component has lots of params (like location data) and an include. My current workaround is to check if nextProps.userId !== this.props.userId and then simply to a forceFetch :-(

Comment: I strongly suspect your fat query is incorrect. Can you update your question with fat query code?

Comment: I see your fat query is incomplete. If you want the whole user and its children updated, you have to include them in the fat query as well. How about you start with including one child of user to the fat query and see if it's working?

Comment: I don't think that's the case because I get 'stuff' from user but not the connection. I think it's because of the params in the connection but I don't wanna pass them along as I don't want to reload with the old parameters as they might have changed in the meantime, also, I don't even have them as the login can happen from any page but this connection request is only from one and I don't want to carry along the params in a global object.

Comment: The component requesting that mutation can pass the connection parameters as `props`. That way, you don't need the global object.

Comment: That would require to have this mutation from only the one component which actually loads the connection, which is not the case, you can do several things without login but once you need a login you can login from any page/component which might has nothing to do with the connection and therefore doesn't know about those props.

Comment: In the mutation, you can check if connection params are provided. Depending on that, you can specify different fat queries. So, check props for connection params and return fat query accordingly.